# Open and modify a powerpoint presentation from a list in excel (the path of each ppt is in a list)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have several powerpoint presentations listed in column A, a title and a text in column B and C and the path of a picture in column D.
Can I use VBA to open each file from column A and update the second slide with title and text of column B and C and then insert picture of column D to the third slide?

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry I think it's more clear now. I have several PowerPoint presentation, I have the list of the path of each one in an excel workbook.

Comment: Yes, you could do this with VBA, and if you run into trouble doing it, people here will try to help you fix problems with your code. They will not write your code for you.